# What's wrong with this initialization of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, unique-ptr

Can somebody tell me, what is wrong with the following initialization of unique_ptr?

```
int main()
{
  unique_ptr<int> py(nullptr);
  py = new int;
  ....
}
```

g++ -O2 xxx.cc -lm -o xxx -std=c++11 says:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are    ‘std::unique_ptr<int>’ and ‘int*’)
   py = new int;
      ^
```

Doing

```
unique_ptr<int> px(new int);
```

works just fine.

Comment: Try `py.reset(new int)`

Comment: or `py = std::make_unique<int>();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The initialization is fine in both pieces of code, `unique_ptr` has [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) for both `nullptr` and naked pointers.

What is failing in the first snippet is the assignment, that is because `unique_ptr` does not have an [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) overload that accepts a naked pointer as its right hand side. It does accept another `unique_ptr` though, so you could do this:

```
py = unique_ptr<int>{new int};
py = std::make_unique<int>(); // Since c++14
```

Or you could look at [`reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) that also accepts a naked pointer and has more or less the same meaning:

```
py.reset(new int);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all who answered - it was very helpfull!

Answer (score 7):

Regarding

> **”** what is wrong with the following initialization of unique_ptr?

It's not the initialization that's problematic, it's the following assignment.

That's where the caret (up arrow) in the error message points: at the assignment. Strong hint: use the `reset` member function, or create a `unique_ptr` instance.

---

Regarding

> doing
>
> ```
> unique_ptr<int> px(new int);
> ```
>
> just works fine.

It's the assignment, of a raw pointer to a `unique_ptr`, that's problematic, not the initialization.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I find your comment offensive.

Comment: And yet you changed the answer.